# Setting a variable global for a class in the constructor Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am sure that this has been answered before, so I humbly apologize in advance.

I have noticed that setting a variable private in the constructor allows the rest of the class to use the variable.

EX:

```
constructor(private foo : bar) { }

...
later in code
...

this.foo
```

My question is simple - why does this work?

(what is angular and typescript doing in the background?)

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the transpiled js file?

Comment: I will next time. I apologize for not doing so beforehand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax of member properties and constructors in angular 2 typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683698/syntax-of-member-properties-and-constructors-in-angular-2-typescript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because TypeScript is defined this way. Prefixing a constructor parameter with `private` or `public` implicitly creates a matching property where the value is assigned. It's just a short form (syntactic sugar) of

```
private foo:bar;
constructor(foo:bar) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
```